# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of a list

Tags: python

I have 2 dictionaries as

```
new_dict = {'A' : {'C10' : 3, 'C11' : 4}, 'B' : {'C11' : 5, 'C12' : 6}}
```

and

```
new_dict1
```

(where key is a comma separated value).

i.e `new_dict1 = { 'A,B' : {'C10' :4, 'C15' : 6}}`

I want to create a new dictionary such that

```
dict_new = {'A' = [{'C10' :4, 'C15' : 6}, {'C10' : 3, 'C11' : 4}], 'B' = [{'C10' :4, 'C15' : 6}, {'C11' : 5, 'C12' : 6}]}
```

I tried with the following code. But its going in an infinite loop. Please help me out.

Code :

```
dict_new = {}
list_new = []
for k, v in new_dict1.items():
    p = k.split(",")
    for x in p:

        list_new.append(v)

        for s, t in new_dict.items():
            if x == s:
                list_new.append(t)
        dict_new[x] = list_new
        new_dict[x] = list_new
        list_new = []
```

Here v and t are again dictionaries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'A' = ` in a dictionary?

Comment: `x = ' '.join(x.split())` ? x is `A` or `B`, why to split it?

Comment: new_dict is a dict of dict @ Willem AND

Removed trimming.. Now pls help me if you know the solution @ Flash

Comment: `dict_new[x] = list(list_new)` ? same with `new_dict[x]` ?

Comment: This is just a sample data.. I have millions of data on which I need to perform this operation.

Comment: what is your questions, I do not get any error with your code

Comment: Its not throwing an error but every key of a dictionary has an infinite loop as a value